# How to config ssl_trusted_certificate of Let’s Encrypt?

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I use `Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator`(https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) to generate a nginx configuration file.

There is a item in the configuration file, like this:

```
ssl_trusted_certificate /path/to/root_CA_cert_plus_intermediates;
```

I use certificate of Let’s Encrypt,how to generate `ssl_trusted_certificate` ?

Answer (score 2):

#### `ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/YOUR_DOMAIN/chain.pem;`

From [Where are my certificates](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#where-are-my-certificates):

> All generated keys and issued certificates can be found in /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain.
>
> ...
>
> If you’re using OCSP stapling with Nginx >= 1.3.7, chain.pem should be provided as the ssl_trusted_certificate to validate OCSP responses.

This information is also in the README file installed by certbot for your domain. Here's a look at the files for my domain:

```sh
root@webserver:/etc/letsencrypt/live/dougrichardson.org$ ls
README  cert.pem  chain.pem  fullchain.pem  privkey.pem
root@webserver:/etc/letsencrypt/live/dougrichardson.org$ cat README
This directory contains your keys and certificates.

`privkey.pem`  : the private key for your certificate.
`fullchain.pem`: the certificate file used in most server software.
`chain.pem`    : used for OCSP stapling in Nginx >=1.3.7.
`cert.pem`     : will break many server configurations, and should not be used
                 without reading further documentation (see link below).

WARNING: DO NOT MOVE OR RENAME THESE FILES!
         Certbot expects these files to remain in this location in order
         to function properly!

We recommend not moving these files. For more information, see the Certbot
User Guide at https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#where-are-my-certificates.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only needed when you have client certificate verification.

```
Syntax: ssl_trusted_certificate file;
Default:    —
Context:    http, server
This directive appeared in version 1.3.7.
Specifies a file with trusted CA certificates in the PEM format used to verify client certificates and OCSP responses if ssl_stapling is enabled.

In contrast to the certificate set by ssl_client_certificate, the list of these certificates will not be sent to clients.
```

I believe this is not need for you, since you are only looking to host a HTTPS site. You just need to comment the directive and you will be good.

Comment: As the document you quoted says, this is also used to verify OCSP responses if ssl_stapling is enabled. It's not just for client certificate verification.